# Can you decrease the width of a video in a video call on Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, webcam

I use a Lenovo webcam that I connect to Macbook Pro using usb. When I am in meetings, the camera shows my entire room because it has this Ultrawide feature.

Is there any way i can decrease the width of the video?

Answer (score 1):

A slightly involved solution would be to use the free software package [OBS](https://obsproject.com).

It is a complete video broadcasting system - but in this particular case you could use it to take in the video from your webcam, crop it and then make it available again as a virtual web camera. On video calls you would select this virtual web camera as the video source.

Note their [guide on virtual cameras](https://obsproject.com/wiki/MacOS-Virtual-Camera-Compatibility-Guide) as some software might require a few extra steps - that is the case if your video meetings take place over for example Microsoft Teams or Skype. Try it first without the extra steps, and then use that guide if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a cardboard matte and just mounting it to restrict the field of view. The video compression will handle optimizing the quality of your intended frame and spend little effort on the black / whatever color you choose and most meeting software now has code to identify and zoom to your face, so others may not even see or mind the black space around you.

Low tech seems a much better fit than trying to inject code into the real time software stack sending the video out and it's cheaper than getting a different camera that does exactly what you need.